# Customizations disapear when sorting or searching list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

Here is my current set up.
I have a sharepoint site where I loaded a javascript file that modifies how the default list looks (I replaced the code with an alert...):

```js
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("test");

 function test() { 
   alert();
 }
```

I then added a script editor web app that contains the following:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/sites/path/script.js">
</script>
```

So when I load the page containing the list, an alert is sent. If I sort the column by clicking on a header, the original html is loaded and then nothing happens, therefore overriding my customizations.

My understanding of the problem is that sharepoint uses a technology that basically just updates parts of the html, and not the hole page. Since the script is set up to run on page load, nothing happens.

How can I set up the page so that whenever the list html changes, the javascript runs, modifying the default look?

Iv'e read a bunch of stuff on the problem, but I don't actually know how to implement any of it...Can you guys point me in the right direction? I have almost zero experience with sharepoint.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have Sharepoint 2013 this behaviour is a feature called "Minimal Download Strategy", turn it off or develop your javascript accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to customizing SharePoint List Views it's always a good practice to specify a SharePoint version since rendering systems varies between versions, for example in SharePoint 2013 the *default* rendering system is so called *Client Side Rendering*. Follow. for example, [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) article for a more details.

Assuming a SharePoint 2013 version, the following example demonstrates how to apply customization to the list (basically the modified version of your example):

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPostRender: 
    function() { console.log('OnPostRender'); }
});
```

> Note: `OnPostRender` event is triggered every time once list view is rendered

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will look into this.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I'm sad that I did not stumble on this page on my own. Thanks a bunch!